# iOS keyboard and textview error - "use of undeclared variable"

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I'm trying to follow the steps in Apple's "Text, Web and Editing Programming Guide for iOS" for *Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard* (p. 36 of the PDF printout), and I keep getting an error in the code that I copied directly from the page (Listing 4-1) which includes this snippet under keyboardDidShow:():

```
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin)){
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

and then listing 4-2:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}
```

(I do have Notifications in place and tested to be working.)

The problem is that Xcode flags the term activeField as an undeclared identifier. Obviously that means I need to declare that somewhere, but as much digging as I have done, I can't figure out *where* to declare it and *how* to declare it.

I have seen in other places where people have used this same code and didn't have a problem. Why me???

For you Xcode veterans, this is probably no big deal, so I am hoping you can educate me.

Thanks!

Comment: `UITextField *activeField` in the `.h` file? If you aren't creating it with code, you'd need to make that an `IBOutlet` as well, and connect it to a text field in Interface Builder.

Comment: Well, that got rid of the errors, but it still doesn't do the job of scrolling the screen up out of the way of the keyboard. But I at least can move forward with it. I actually thought I had tried that, but maybe I mistyped it. Everything starts to all run together for me. But I did remember to set an outlet. Thanks!

Comment: Update: It is working! I just need to iron out a few wrinkles, but otherwise, I am in good shape. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Bill, I've run into the same exact problem as you... care to share how you fixed it?

Comment: My 59-year-old brain has been through a lot since August, and I don't remember exactly what I did. It seems like wquist's answer fixed the problem in general, but the wrinkles I mention were just tweaks to some of the numbers to make it scroll to the proper position. My code shows that in the above segment (first box) I commented out the "if(!CGRectContainsPoint..." and just made the "CGPoint scrollPoint = " segment unconditional. Write me at wanorman2000@yahoo.com and I'll send you the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable in the main view controller:

```
@implementation MainViewController {
    UITextField *activeField;
}
```